# Matlab GUI, why only 1 button group is working?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, radio-button, buttongroup

I am preparing simple GUI, but at the beginning I have faced serious problem.

Mygui consists of 2 groups of buttons:

- groupA

  (buttona1, buttona2)
- groupB

  (buttonb1, buttonb2)

And 2 'edit text' fields:

- density
- volume

Idea is that chosing `buttona2` from `groupA`, turns off first "edit text" (make it gray), and clicking on `buttona1` turns it on again.

At this moment everything works fine.

The problem is that `groupB` should work the same way with the second "edit text", but it doesn't.

I have noticed that clicking in `groupB` doesnt even couse calling function:

```
function groupB_SelectionChangeFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
```

Whole code:

```
function varargout = testgui(varargin)
% TESTGUI MATLAB code for testgui.fig
%      TESTGUI, by itself, creates a new TESTGUI or raises the existing
%      singleton*.
%
%      H = TESTGUI returns the handle to a new TESTGUI or the handle to
%      the existing singleton*.
%
%      TESTGUI('CALLBACK',hObject,eventData,handles,...) calls the local
%      function named CALLBACK in TESTGUI.M with the given input arguments.
%
%      TESTGUI('Property','Value',...) creates a new TESTGUI or raises
%      the existing singleton*.  Starting from the left, property value pairs are
%      applied to the GUI before testgui_OpeningFcn gets called.  An
%      unrecognized property name or invalid value makes property application
%      stop.  All inputs are passed to testgui_OpeningFcn via varargin.
%
%      *See GUI Options on GUIDE's Tools menu.  Choose "GUI allows only one
%      instance to run (singleton)".
%
% See also: GUIDE, GUIDATA, GUIHANDLES

% Edit the above text to modify the response to help testgui

% Last Modified by GUIDE v2.5 04-Dec-2014 16:56:27

% Begin initialization code - DO NOT EDIT
gui_Singleton = 1;
gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
                   'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
                   'gui_OpeningFcn', @testgui_OpeningFcn, ...
                   'gui_OutputFcn',  @testgui_OutputFcn, ...
                   'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
                   'gui_Callback',   []);
if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
    gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
end

if nargout
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
else
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
end
% End initialization code - DO NOT EDIT

% --- Executes just before testgui is made visible.
function testgui_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
% This function has no output args, see OutputFcn.
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
% varargin   command line arguments to testgui (see VARARGIN)

% Choose default command line output for testgui
handles.output = hObject;

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);

initialize_gui(hObject, handles, false);

% UIWAIT makes testgui wait for user response (see UIRESUME)
% uiwait(handles.figure1);


% --- Outputs from this function are returned to the command line.
function varargout = testgui_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% varargout  cell array for returning output args (see VARARGOUT);
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Get default command line output from handles structure
varargout{1} = handles.output;


% --- Executes during object creation, after setting all properties.
function density_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to density (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    empty - handles not created until after all CreateFcns called

% Hint: popupmenu controls usually have a white background on Windows.
%       See ISPC and COMPUTER.
if ispc && isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
    set(hObject,'BackgroundColor','white');
end



function density_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to density (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hints: get(hObject,'String') returns contents of density as text
%        str2double(get(hObject,'String')) returns contents of density as a double
density = str2double(get(hObject, 'String'));
if isnan(density)
    set(hObject, 'String', 0);
    errordlg('Input must be a number','Error');
end

% Save the new density value
handles.metricdata.density = density;
guidata(hObject,handles)

% --- Executes during object creation, after setting all properties.
function volume_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to volume (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    empty - handles not created until after all CreateFcns called

% Hint: popupmenu controls usually have a white background on Windows.
%       See ISPC and COMPUTER.
if ispc && isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
    set(hObject,'BackgroundColor','white');
end



function volume_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to volume (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hints: get(hObject,'String') returns contents of volume as text
%        str2double(get(hObject,'String')) returns contents of volume as a double
volume = str2double(get(hObject, 'String'));
if isnan(volume)
    set(hObject, 'String', 0);
    errordlg('Input must be a number','Error');
end

% Save the new volume value
handles.metricdata.volume = volume;
guidata(hObject,handles)



% --- Executes when selected object changed in groupA.
function groupA_SelectionChangeFcn(hObject, ~, handles)
% hObject    handle to the selected object in groupA 
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

if (hObject == handles.buttona1)
    set(handles.density, 'Enable', 'on');
else
    set(handles.density, 'Enable', 'off');
end

% --- Executes when selected object changed in groupB.
function groupB_SelectionChangeFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to the selected object in groupB 
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

if (hObject == handles.buttonb1)
    set(handles.volume, 'Enable', 'on');
else
    set(handles.volume, 'Enable', 'off');
end

% --------------------------------------------------------------------
function initialize_gui(fig_handle, handles, isreset)
% If the metricdata field is present and the reset flag is false, it means
% we are we are just re-initializing a GUI by calling it from the cmd line
% while it is up. So, bail out as we dont want to reset the data.
if isfield(handles, 'metricdata') && ~isreset
    return;
end

handles.metricdata.density = 0;
handles.metricdata.volume  = 0;

set(handles.density, 'String', handles.metricdata.density);
set(handles.volume,  'String', handles.metricdata.volume);


set(handles.groupA, 'SelectedObject', handles.buttona1);
set(handles.groupB, 'SelectedObject', handles.buttonb1);


% Update handles structure
guidata(handles.figure1, handles);
```

`.fig` file is included.

Comment: I suspect your `buttonb1` and `buttonb2` do not belong to the `groupB`. That would explain why no event is triggered when you click them.

Comment: where is the .fig file?

Comment: Hoki, that would make sanse. But I have already changed my concept so its fine. I will try to figure it out after i finish my project and publish the solution.